# PHPExcel having trouble opening an XML file (Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag results invalid)

Tags: php, xml, phpexcel

I save the XML generated from a URL to an XML file. Then I try to open it with PHP and save it as Excel2007 file using PHPExcel. But I get the following for each tag in the XML data file, every single one:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag (note: this tag name here changes for every tag)results invalid in
>   ./data.xml, line: 2 in C:\wamp\www\project\inc\functions.inc.php on
>   line 48

and this at the very end of the page with all the warnings:

> Fatal error: Class 'SimpleXML' not found in
>   C:\wamp\www\project\inc\functions.inc.php on line 58

This is the code:

```
$sxml->asXML('data.xml'); // save as xml to server
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
$dom->recover = true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('./data.xml'); // LINE 48

if (!$dom)
{
    throw new Exception("Could not load the lax XML file");
}
// Now you can work with your XML file using the $dom object.

// If you'd like using SimpleXML, do the following steps.
$xml = new SimpleXML($dom->saveXML()); // LINE 58
unset($dom);
/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$inputFileName = "./data.xml";
/**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
/**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  **/
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
/**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```

Comment: seems kind of silly to load your xml file into DOM, spit out the DOM as xml, and load it into SimpleXML... especially since it looks like simplexml is not installed on your host.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing. I was given the impression that loading though dom after saving it asXML() first would remove the lax from XML.

Comment: Nice. My code file just got overwritten somehow by PHPExcel. Can't go back and undo. *Sigh*